# Change navigation menu class and reveal sub tree menu on scroll or click

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am after creating a sidebar menu which when you click or scroll shows sub menus, similar to the bootstrap menu found here: -

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview

I have the following: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Dxtyu/140/

But im not sure how to get the same effect as the bootstrap menu, where it reveals the sub menus on scroll or click.

Is there a way to add this into the fiddle with the code I have or do I need a plugin for this?

```
<div class="m1 menu">
<div id="menu-center">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
 <div id="home"></div>
 <div id="portfolio"></div>
 <div id="about"></div>
 <div id="contact"></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Sidebar Scrolling, Affix & Scrollspy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482114/bootstrap-sidebar-scrolling-affix-scrollspy)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might help you...
First you need a submenu:

```
<li><a href="#about">About</a>
    <ul><li>SUB</li></ul>
</li>
```

then something like:

```
.menu ul ul {
    display:none;
}
.menu ul li.active ul {
    display:block;
}
```

and setting active on `<li>`, not `<a>`

```
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
```

here the fiddle, just quick and dirty for showing:
http://jsfiddle.net/9R6cH/

Comment: is it possible for the active links to carry on through the sub menu as well, as you scroll?

Answer (score 0):

### Bootstrap's example uses a variation of `scrollspy` ( with `affix` )

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

You can create the effect you want by monitoring the `activate.bs.scrollspy` event.

When that event fires, you can use the `target` provided in the event object to determine what to expand in your menu. Then you need to add/remove the `.hidden` class on your sub-menu.

**Here is a bootply showing you how to trap the event:** http://bootply.com/112361

Also, you will notice that your ( great ) approach to scroll detection is a duplication of `scrollspy` also.